# UPDATE table with shift by ID

Tags: mysql, set, insert-update

I am looking to **update a table with a new column**, while referencing a previous row in another column.

```
ID | Fruit  | Fruit_prev |
-------------------------
1  | Apple  |            |
2  | Orange | Apple      |
3  | Banana | Orange     |
4  | Lemon  | Banana     |
```

The Fruit_prev does not exist in the original table and I am trying to add it with UPDATE column.

My thought goes around this:

```sql
UPDATE table SET Fruit_prev = (SELECT Fruit WHERE ID = ID-1);
```

however, this does not work in MYSQL.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Your solution would do for me. It get the job done unless we are talking about millions or even billions of records.

Comment: It will work perfectly until the ID order will not breaks

Comment: Thanks, the code I proposed gives a syntax error... hence me asking for help here...

Comment: Also, I understand I should be doing inner join by ID, along the lines of:: 

UPDATE Fruit SET PrevFruit =ST2.Fruit
FROM Fruit ST
INNER JOIN Fruit ST2
ON ST.ID - 1 = ST2.ID;

but I still can´t get this to work...can someone help, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE by default ID:

```
UPDATE FruitTable AS ft
INNER JOIN FruitTable AS ft2
    ON ft.ID - 1 = ft2.ID
SET ft.Fruit_prev = ft2.Fruit
```

UPDATE with +1 shift by any column (It's Date column here):

```
UPDATE
Fruit as t0
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT ft.*, 
         @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
    FROM Fruit ft, 
         (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
  ORDER BY Date) AS t1
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT ft.*, 
         @rownum2 := @rownum2 + 1 AS rank
    FROM Fruit ft, 
         (SELECT @rownum2 := 0) r
  ORDER BY Date) AS t2
ON t0.Id = t1.Id AND t1.rank - 1= t2.rank
SET t0.FruitPrev = t2.Fruit;
```

Three tables are joined here. The 1st is defaul so it could be updatable, the 2nd and  the 3rd with addition of ranking by `Date` so they could be shifted +1 by that `rank` field.

Comment: PS: my prev example was for sql-server, this example should work for mysql. Please, check it!

Comment: btw - do I already need to have the new column ("Fruit_prev") in the schema or will this be added as part of the "Update" command?

Comment: No, cause UPDATE is "data manipulation language" command (DML). But to add column you should use ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column_name datatype - "data definition language" command (DDL)

Comment: Works!! Thank you, Ivan!!

Comment: @Stan, you're welcome! BTW it would be a great challenge for you to make this update with shift by e.g. Date column as I proposed in sql-server example (cause that's a real life task)

Comment: @Stan, now you can see an example of update with shift by any column, that's more useful in real life

Comment: Thanks again, Ivan, for extending help on this. Both thumbs up!